# MysqlDataTruncation error on insert

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Connecting to a selected database...
Connected database successfully...
Inserting records into the table...
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'st_phno' at row 1Goodbye!

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4072)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2713)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1712)
at insert.Katal.main(Katal.java:24)
```

I have created the database named as Katal and table in database named as Student.
I gave one column as (st_phno int(10)).
When I insert value of st_phno as 9876543210, it throws above exception.
help for correcting the program

Comment: Add code with table metadata

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include **(1)** the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` on the table in question, and **(2)** the relevant Java code that is trying to perform the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html), an integer can take on the following range:

```
-2147483648 to 2147483647
```

When you try to insert the value `9876543210` into the `st_phno` column, MySQL *first* has to run a validity check that the integer you inserted is within range.  It fails this check since it is *larger* than the maximum allowed value of `2147483647`.

The error you got is a bit misleading, because your insert never even gets as far as the case to `varchar` because insertion.  The message makes it appear that MySQL rejected a perfectly valid 10 character string from being inserted into a column of width 10.  This isn't the cause of the error message, and you can verify this yourself by inserting, for example, the ten digit number `2000000000`.

**Workaround:**

Since your `st_phon` column is `varchar`, you can `INSERT` a string inside of an integer.  So I would expect the following query to succeed without error:

```
INSERT INTO Student (`st_phon`) VALUES ('9876543210');
```

This should work because there would no longer be a check of the input as an integer.  The only check would be to make sure the width of the `varchar` has a width of 10 or less, which it does.

Comment: Please mark correct if it answered your question, thanks.